# Parameterized Decorators in Python

Tags: python, python-decorators

I have been experimenting with different kinds of decorators in Python and I am finding it difficult to understand Parameterized decorators.
A decorator accepts callables and returns callable (callable being a function in my case)
In the following code:-

```
def check_non_negative(index):
    def validator(f):
        def wrap(*args):
            if args[index]<0:
                raise ValueError(
                    'Argument {} must be non negative.'.format(index))
            return f(*args)
        return wrap
    return validator

@check_non_negative(1)
def create_list(value,size):
    return [value]*size


create_list('a',3)
```

Here I see that check_non_negative is not a decorator according to the definition but behaves like one (During run Validator is the actual decorator). check_non_negative takes an integer and not a callable, yet it behaves like decorator. Can somebody explain why?

Comment: Where is ``check_non_integer`` ?

Comment: Sorry typo, edited with corrections

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/how-to-make-a-chain-of-function-decorators/1594484#1594484 help (scroll to "Passing Arguments to the Decorator")?

Answer (score 4):

`check_non_negative` is not technically a decorator by your definition, one might call it a 'decorator factory'. It returns `validator`, which *is* a decorator.

Basically whenever you have:

```
@<expression>
def ...
```

then `<expression>` must evaluate to a decorator, i.e. a callable which accepts a single argument that is also a callable.

Comment: aaaah.. Right, it's a decorator factory which is returning validator as a decorator. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you pass parameters to a decorator function (i.e. `@check_non_negative(1)`), the function is invoked with those parameters, and then it returns a decorator that takes and returns a function (like if you'd used `@validator` with no parameters).

It's easier to understand with type annotations IMO:

```
import functools
from typing import cast, Callable, List, TypeVar


_Elem = TypeVar('_Elem')
_Func = TypeVar('_Func', bound=Callable)


def check_non_negative(index: int) -> Callable[[_Func], _Func]:
    def validator(f: _Func) -> _Func:
        @functools.wraps(f)
        def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
            if args[index] < 0:
                raise ValueError(
                    'Argument {} must be non negative.'.format(index))
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return cast(_Func, wrap)
    return validator


@check_non_negative(1)
def create_list(value: _Elem, size: int) -> List[_Elem]:
    return [value]*size
```

So `check_non_negative` takes an `int` argument, and returns a function (`validator`) that takes a specific type of function (`_Func`, which here refers to the type of the decorated function, e.g. `create_list`) and returns the same type of function.

Comment: As Alex said above I agree with the fact that check_non_integer is a decorator factory that is returning a validator for me.